# Change image source inside wpf listview DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have a listview in a wpf window as following

```
<ListView Name="lvInstructors" ItemsSource="{Binding Instructors}">
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="3">
                            </UniformGrid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="http://localhost:30870/Content/img/avatar1.jpg" Width="30px"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding InstructorName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Qualifications}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="InstructorRating">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rating}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

I need to change the image source attribute, which is located inside the first stackPanel programmatically, how can I do that?

Comment: Why not Bind it to an Image or ImageSource Property of an Instructor? This way you get an avatar/image for every instructor in your Instructors list.

Comment: I need to get each image from a remote service

Comment: That is not a real reason, why you should not do this via binding. You are probably querying teh service for the Instructor, either you are getting the image or source path right there. Or you requery right in the Getter of the Image Property (which i would not suggest)

Comment: so you think the best solution is to data bind the source rather than getting it at runtime?

Comment: No, you are alwys getting the image at runtime, since you are querying a Service.I will post an answer, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your xaml-Code:

```
<ListView Name="lvInstructors" ItemsSource="{Binding Instructors}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3">
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="30px"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding InstructorName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Qualifications}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="InstructorRating">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rating}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Now, since we don't know how your code works i will just post snippets:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Instructor> Instructors {get; set}

    public void RetrieveInstructorsFromService()
    {
         // the service needs to populate all properties of the Instructor isntance.
         var instructors = service.GetInstructors();
         this.Instructors = new ObservableCollection<Instructor>(instructors);
    }
}

public class Instructor
{
    [...]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Now your list will display all Instructors from the service with their corresponding avatar-image.